# How can I close the identify result dialog programmatically?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to close the identify result dialog which appeared when I select to identify a feature from the active layer. Does someone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dlg = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog, 'QgsIdentifyResultsBase')
dlg.close()
```

Or you can hide it with `dlg.hide()`.

Comment: How can i open the dialogue it it's not there ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i get your problem, but the identify tool dialog is only open if you toogle the info button in the toolbox (see left icon in the box below).

If you just wanna select a feature, then use the select feature button (the icon at the right end in the picture). Holding CTRL on your keyboard enables you to select multiple features ad once.

[image]

Comment: OK , do you know how can i can i close the dialog from python plugin?